# Confused about middleware functions' routes

Tags: node.js, express

When there is a get request to the root

```
app.get("/", (req, res)=>res.sendFile(__dirname+"/views/index.html") )
```

sends a file back.

Now, this function

```
app.use("/", express.static("public"))
```

is interpreted in the same way? I would expect

```
https://myaddress.com/style.css
```

not to return anything as the request it not to the root `/` but to `/style.css`

How should I interpret the function then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.use("/", ...)` will match any path that starts with a `/`.   So,

```
app.use("/", express.static("public"))
```

will attempt a match with every single URL that it sees (since they all start with `/`) and is in fact the same as:

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

because the default path for `app.use()` is `/` when none is specified.

`app.use()` is different than `app.get()`, `app.post()`, etc.. in this regard.

Direct from the [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use) for `app.use()`:

> A route will match any path that follows its path immediately with a “/”. For example: app.use('/apple', ...) will match “/apple”, “/apple/images”, “/apple/images/news”, and so on.

Whereas `app.get('/apple', ...)` will only match `/apple`.  It will not match `/apple/images`.  `app.use()` is more permissive in its matching.

Comment: But, for example, when a stylesheet is in the page, if I write `app.get(/, ....)` it should catch that route too. And it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @santimirandarp - `app.get('/', ...)` only matches the exact request of `/`.  It would not match a stylesheet request like `/stylesheet.css`.  Only `app.use()` matches any path that starts with what you specify.

Comment: thank you, so `.use` kindof seaches recursively for the file.

Comment: @santimirandarp - No, there's no recursive anything with `app.use()`.  If you do `app.use('/test', ...)`, then that will match any URL where the path starts with `/test`.  It must START with that.  It will match `/test`, `/test/hello` and `/test/hello/file.html`.  It will not match `/something/test`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, now things are finally fitting together.